# One to many and many to many connection issue. Not connecting properly

Tags: mongodb, connection, many-to-many, one-to-many, prisma

```
model owner {
  ownerId      String @id @default (auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  property     property[]     @relation(fields: [propertyId], references: [propertyId])
  propertyId   String[]       @db.ObjectId
  propertyrole propertyrole[]
}

model property {
  propertyId     String @id @default (auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  ownerId        String[]       @db.ObjectId
  owner          owner[]        @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [ownerId])
  propertyrole   propertyrole[]
}
```

these are my relations in prisma with mongodb but while updating owner it is getting connected by property but property is not getting updated with that specific owner.
I'm expecting the connection in both tables.

Comment: Related GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18691

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
In many to many , I connected with this query:

```
const updateOwnerData = await prisma.owner.update({
where: { ownerId: mongoID },
data: {
property: {
connect: [{
propertyId: propertyData.propertyId
}]
}
}
})
```